# Getting strange data after adding a foreign constraint in symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 simple entities in my app:**Product** and **Category** which are related by the *ManyToOne* relation:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Product
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="product")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Product
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
         * @ORM\KoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
         */
        private $category;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         *
         * @return Product
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         *
         * @param string $description
         *
         * @return Product
         */
        public function setDescription($description)
        {
            $this->description = $description;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get description
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getDescription()
        {
            return $this->description;
        }

        /**
         * @return int
         */
        public function getCategory()
        {
            return $this->category;
        }

        /**
         * @param int $category
         */
        public function setCategory($category)
        {
            $this->category = $category;
        }
    }

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The relation is working fine.But there is a problem.When i try to fetch my objects from DB by

```
public function indexAction(){
        $products = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->findAll();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($products);die;
    }
```

it returns a tone of code, like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Product Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Product:private] => 1
            [name:AppBundle\Entity\Product:private] => Samsung Galaxy S5
            [description:AppBundle\Entity\Product:private] => Stylish and elegant!
            [category:AppBundle\Entity\Product:private] => Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Category Object
                (
                    [__initializer__] => Closure Object
                        (
                            [static] => Array
                                (
                                    [entityPersister] => Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister Object
                                        (
                                            [class:protected] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => AppBundle\Entity\Category
                                                    [namespace] => AppBundle\Entity
                                                    [rootEntityName] => AppBundle\Entity\Category
                                                    [customGeneratorDefinition] => 
                                                    [customRepositoryClassName] => 
                                                    [isMappedSuperclass] => 
                                                    [isEmbeddedClass] => 
                                                    [parentClasses] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [subClasses] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [embeddedClasses] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [namedQueries] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [namedNativeQueries] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [sqlResultSetMappings] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )
```

and a lot more, which is unpossible to present here entirely.
I will very appreciate if someone suggests me how to get rid of all this unnecessary data and recieve only my object's properties.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because Doctrine by default loads associations as Proxies which are references to real entities. Then when you try to fetch something from that association, Doctrine really fetches data from database and hydrates it. This is commonly called *Lazy loading* and is useful for performance improving.

To solve that you have to set eager fetch mode on your association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

to get results as arrays

Comment: I have also some troubles with gathering the related products in my category object.There is an example on symfony's official site, like gathering all products in an array, but that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What troubles? Why it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: First I can't imagine how it must take up parameters and second when i try just copy and past that, my php storm doesn't generate getter and setter for that.But bellow in example it shows how are datas recived by:public function showProductsAction($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Category::class)
        ->find($categoryId);

    $products = $category->getProducts();

    // ...
}

Comment: you can add setters/getters manually. In example you've written you get category and then all products from that category, which seems logic.

Comment: Thank you very much.Now is everything ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use Symfony Serializer (or JMS Serializer) for this.

You will be able, for example, to simply configure output as various sets of fields of your entities(using serialization groups), hide some fields and show only IDs of related entities.

Basic documentation is here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a debug output, which is better readable than a "print_r()", you can use

```
use \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
...
echo "<pre>";
Debug::dump($products);
...
```